# Is the 'angel of the abyss' (Rev 9:11) the self-same 'angel' -- who has the 'key to the abyss' (Rev 20:1)?

Tags: revelation, prophecy, symbolism

> Rev 9:11
>   They had as king over them **the angel of the Abyss**, whose name in Hebrew is Abaddon and in Greek is Apollyon (that is, Destroyer).
>
> Rev 20:1
>   And I saw an **angel** coming down out of heaven, **having the key to the Abyss** and holding in his hand a great chain.

Is it the same angel in both instances? And is it God's angel?

Comment: As Jesus is "The Word" (John 1:1), thus God's greatest spokesman, if I can use that phrase, then that would also make him God's Greatest Messenger or in Greek  "Anggelos."

Answer (score 1):

WHO IS THE “ANGEL OF THE ABYSS” the SAME Angel has the "key of the Abyss".

What do the scriptures say?

1st What can the angel do?

> Rev. 9:11
>   “They have over them a king, the angel of the abyss. In Hebrew his name is Abaddon*, but in Greek he has the name Apollyon**.”
>   *Means “Destruction.”     **Means “Destroyer.”

This angel has the power to Destroy!  What or who?

2nd What other kind of power does the angel have?

> Rev. 20:1-3
>   And I saw an angel coming down out of heaven with the key of the abyss and a great chain in his hand. 2 He seized* the dragon, the original serpent, who is the Devil* and Satan*, and bound him for 1,000 years. 3 And he hurled him into the abyss and shut it and sealed it over him, so that he would not mislead the nations anymore until the 1,000 years were ended. After this he must be released for a little while.”

The Angel has controling power over Satan The Devil to put him into the abbys and the release him from the abyss at will.

3rd Who has been given power over Satan The Devil to destroy him?

> Gen. 3:15-16 KJV
>   “And the LORD God said unto the serpent (Devil), Because thou (Devil) hast done this, thou [art] cursed above all cattle, and above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust shalt thou eat all the days of thy life:  15 And I will put enmity between thee (Devil) and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed ; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.”

4th Who is The “Seed”?

> Gen. 3:15 “…this purpose of God that Jesus Christ was born of a virgin; this, and this alone, is what is implied in the promise of the seed of the woman bruising the head of the serpent. Jesus Christ died to put away sin by the sacrifice of himself, and to destroy him who had the power of death, that is, the devil.”-‘CLARKE’S COMMENTARY OT, VOLUME 1, GENESIS – DEUTERONOMY’ by Adam Clarke

The first Biblical prophecy identifies Jesus as the one commissioned by God to destroy Satan the Devil!

This is supported by:-

> Heb. 2:14
>   “Therefore, since the “young children” are sharers of blood and flesh, he (Jesus) also similarly shared in the same things, so that through his (Jesus) death he (Jesus) might bring to nothing the one having the means to cause death, that is, the Devil, ..”
>
> 1 John 3:8
>   “For this purpose the Son of God (Jesus) was made manifest, to break up the works of the Devil.”

Right from the onset of God’s revelation to mankind, starting in Genesis, about his purpose, he states a prime idea; that Jesus (the seed) is the one who God foretold will be the ‘destroyer’ of Satan The Devil.  The Scripture do not identify anyone one else for this role!  So it is reasonable to conclude that the “angel of the abyss” etc. is non other the Jesus Christ acting as God’s champion bring his arch enemy to nothing!

AS THEY BOTH HAVE POWER OVER SATAN AND ONLY ONE PERSON HAS THAT POWER, JESUS, THEN THEY ARE BOTH JESUS AT WORK UNDER OTHER TITLES!!

Comment: Thankyou ethos. I can accept that the “angel of the abyss” (who binds Satan) is Jesus Christ.  BUT can 'aggelos'  meaning 'messenger' actually refer to Jesus Christ?

Comment: This answer actually ASSUMES that the two angels are the same.  This is the point of the question - please provide an argument to show that they are the same.

Comment: As Jesus is "The Word" (John 1:1), thus God's greatest spokesman, if I can use that phrase, then that would also make him God's Greatest Messenger or in Greek  "Anggelos."

Comment: At John 7:16 (NJB) Jesus said: "'My teaching is not from myself: it comes from the one who sent me;.."  As Jesus was "sent" by God and spoke what God told him to and he speaks "not of 'himself'" then he brings God message to mankind, thus a Messenger of God; God's Angel ("the angel of the LORD").

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the same angel in both instances?

No. One is a heavenly angel working for God and is the same angel in Revelation 20 that possesses the key and imprisons Satan. The angel of the pit never has the key because God's enemies are never given control of a place where God imprisons them. That's like giving a leader of a gang in prison the keys to the prison doors.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that Death and Hell are Sheol and Abaddon, which suggests that Apollyon is defeated after the Dragon (since D&H are cast into the Lake of Fire after the Dragon is, Rev. 20:14). There was a tradition recorded in the Gospel of Nicodemus according to which Hell was dominated by both Satan and an unnamed (IIRC) "prince of Hell," who (again IIRC) was scornful of Satan, or not under his command, or something like that.

Note also 1 Corinthians 15:26, which is variously translated as, "The last enemy destroyed/abolished/done away with is death."

All things considered, you can interpret Apollyon as the angel who binds Satan for the Millennium, without assuming that he is Christ.

Answer (score 0):

The Angel that locked up the dragon  was not Abaddon,neither was the one who unlocked the pit.Abaddon was among those coming out of the pit and was their King.All These are  in the same Chapter.
Jesus is not any of this angels mentioned in the binding and Release of the devil(i.e.its not yet the destruction of the devil which comes later).After Jesus came He is referred to very clearly as Jesus not as any angel.Remember on ascending He was placed above ALL Angels.He comes to destroy the devil finally at the Armageddon battle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).